# Play framework, how do you access cookie in client side(javascript)?

Tags: java, scala, cookies, playframework

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security  for my REST endpoint.

I set the returning result of my implementation with Scala Play `result.withCookies(Cookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken))`.

But, in the client side(js), somehow when i try to access using `document.cookie`. The cookie is not found.

With using the Java API of `response().setCookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken)` seems different though. Its accessible via `document.cookie`.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that `httpOnly` is set to true (it's so by default) in your `application.conf`. This means that you can't read your cookies in your JavaScript on the client side.
Put `session.httpOnly=false` in your `application.conf`.

But consider the [security implications](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/).

Comment: How 'insecure' do you think setting httpOnly to false would be ? Since, I see no other way for my JS to read the token cookie data via server. Would it be safe enough using HTTPS only ?

Comment: HTTPS doesn't prevent cookie stealing via XSS like explained in the article.

Comment: To add some details, play doesn't stop you setting *other* cookies for your less secure data `Ok(views.html.index()).withCookies(Cookie("key","value"))`. These are accessable from javascript by default without exposing your main cookie

Answer (score 1):

Play sets the `HttpOnly` flag on its cookies by default, so they wont be accessible via clientside code (js). From Google:

> HttpOnly is an additional flag included in a Set-Cookie HTTP response header. Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of client side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser supports it).

See [here](http://www.noppanit.com/angularjs-cookies-with-play-framework-2-1-1-java-session/) for a possible way to turn this off. Particualarly:

> So, it Play 1 you can set application.session.httpOnly=false but in Play 2.1 they changed to session.httpOnly=false

Those should be set in your application.conf i believe. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Play 2.5.x, where the other answers involving `application.conf` didn't.

```
Cookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken, httpOnly = false)
```

This might be because `application.sesssion` only deals with sesssion cookies. For internationalization cookies, for example, you have to modify `play.i18n.langCookieHttpOnly`, and so on.

The aforementioned solution, on the other hand, deals with cookies individually.